# Метод простых итераций С++

Tags: c++

Как сделать код чтобы она решала систему нелинейных уравнений с двумя переменными  методом простых итераций

Это нужно реализовать это так чтобы пользователь вводил к-во итераций, точность, и начальное приближение.

Comment: Какую конкретно систему?

Comment: Я прямо уверен, что видел точно такой же вопрос несколько дней назад.

Comment: @Harry x^2+y^2=34 xy=15

Answer (score 1):

Немного преобразуем систему, выразив y из второго уравнения и подставив в первое. Дальше все просто.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const double eps = 1e-8;
    double y = 1, x = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        double xx = x, yy = y;
        x = sqrt(34-15/x/x);
        y = 15/x;

        if (abs(xx-x)< eps && abs(yy-y)< eps) break;
    }

    cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << endl;
}
```

На самом деле решений 4, но, понятно, что процесс сходится только к одному решению (не может же он одновременно сходиться к четырем :))

В силу симметрии из решения (x,y) получаются решения (y,x), (-x,-y) и (-y,-x)...

Comment: Извините но нужно реализовать это так чтобы пользователь вводил к-во итераций, точность, и начальное приближение как в коде который был дан выше @Harry

Comment: Ну добавьте. Точность в eps, количество - еще в одну переменную и цикл завершать при ее обнулении (уменьшать на 1 в цикле)... Это вы уже хотите чтоб за вас полностью работу сделали. Нет уж, потрудитесь хоть немного...